# how can i print output of a python file with subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, subprocess

im trying to make an code that everytime that the user will enter the word "Hello",
the code will print the output of Hello.py that is located in the same path as my code, but it does not work
the problem is in the elif(input == "Hello")

the error that i got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "C:\Users\Nir Nir\Desktop\shell\check.py", line 34, in <module>
> j = subprocess.check_output('python ' + PATH_OF_SCRIPTS + '\\' + input.split(' ')[0] + '.py', shell = True)   
> File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)  
> CalledProcessError: Command 'python C:\Users\Nir Nir\Desktop\shell\Hello.py' returned non-zero exit status 2
> ```

```
import os
import subprocess

#------
PATH_OF_SCRIPTS = os.path.abspath("")
print PATH_OF_SCRIPTS
#------


path = os.path.abspath("")
print str(path),">"
check = 0

while True:
    check = 1
    if(check != 0):
        input = raw_input()
        if(input == "exit"):
            break
        if(input == "dir"): # shows the files in the current folder
            from os import listdir
            from os.path import isfile, join
            onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
            print onlyfiles
        elif(input.startswith("cd")): # change the current folder if the user wants to do it
            split = input.split(" ")
            if((os.path.isdir(split[1]) == True)): # checks if path is exists 
                path = split[1]
                print path + ">"
            else:
                print "error: no path like this"
                print path + ">"
        elif(input == "Hello"): *** here is the problem
            j = subprocess.check_output('python ' + PATH_OF_SCRIPTS + '\\' + input.split(' ')[0] + '.py', shell = True)
            print j

        else:
            print "there is no command like this"



        #import os
        #listdir = os.listdir(path)
        #print listdir
```

Comment: **the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\New folder\shell\check.py", line 34, in <module>
    j = subprocess.check_output('python ' + PATH_OF_SCRIPTS + '\\' + input.split(' ')[0] + '.py', shell = True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command 'python C:\Users\Public\New folder\shell\Hello.py' returned non-zero exit status 2**

Comment: this is not the reason. i tried to run it from another user and it shows me the same error ^. btw, can you please remove my name (N.A) from you message? thanks